# I get AxisFault 501 : not implemented in every Axis2 WS call in my project

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, apache-axis

I am pretty new to Axis2 but have already used several SOAP softwares and webservices. I joined a new project recently (common Java EE project with a Tomcat v7.0 server) and after retrieving the existing code from the repo, I always get AxisFault errors when I try to use the stubs :

> Exception in findDocumentContent() - Axis fault
>
> Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 501 Error: Not Implemented

I tried to follow the instructions given in this thread : [org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 501 Error: Not Implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770835/org-apache-axis2-axisfault-transport-error-501-error-not-implemented)

But it seems to be more like a workaround, even worse, it throws other errors ("Not in GZIP format", "Unknown reference identifier"...) and I'm surprised as my teammates have no problem with that. I tried to compare my axis2 config with theirs, could not find anything different...

So I am trying to figure out what may cause these exceptions that occur in EVERY module of the project when I have to call an Axis2 WS, but only with my workspace.

For information, here is how a stub is basically created and implemented in this project :

```
MyServiceStub stub;
String endpoint = RefsGeneral.getUrlMyService();

stub = (MyServiceStub) MyServiceStubConnectionPools.getInstance().borrowStub(endpoint,
MyServiceStub.class, 60000, false);    

// The 501 not implemented AxisFault occurs on this line
MyServiceResponseDocument response = stub.getResponseDocument(params);

// Below, the borrowStub method :

public Stub borrowStub(String serviceURL, Class stubClass, 
final int timeOut, final boolean connectionNotChunked) throws Exception {
    Stub stub = null;

    try {
        stub = StubFactory.createStubAvecAuthentification(serviceUrl);
    } catch (AxisFault e) {  }

    return stub;
}
```

Any idea of what may be wrong will be appreciated... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a WebService in Tomcat the best way is to use maven plugin or configure Eclipse adding axis2 runtime in preferences.

There is a Wizard in Eclipse where you can choose a Main method and axis2 runtime from a existing project.

When you have finished this wizard you will see new folders in your project with the configuration and the administration pages. Then you have to deploy it in your Tomcat exporting that project as a WAR file or deploying directly if you have integrated it in your IDE.

Also you can configure user permisions and WS security in Tomcat configuration files such as tomcat-users and web.xml.

I hope this information could be useful for you.